# Scrapy:Sitemap spider and gzipped files

Tags: sitemap, scrapy

I tried running the sitemap spider but it refused to crawl  gzipped 
sitemaps.It gave the following error

```
[scrapy] WARNING: Ignoring non-XML sitemap
```

is there a setting that needs to be enabled to allow parsing of 
gzipped sitemaps?

I use scrapy version 0.15

Answer (score 5):

Scrapy should automatically unzip the gzipped content.

See the responsible code in [contrib/spiders/sitemap.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/sitemap.py)

```
        if isinstance(response, XmlResponse):
            body = response.body
        elif is_gzipped(response):
            body = gunzip(response.body)
        else:
            log.msg("Ignoring non-XML sitemap: %s" % response, log.WARNING)
            return
```

I think either the XML is malformed, or the file isn't gzipped with the proper headers. I suggest trying the same spider on a sitemap of which you are sure of it's formatting.

If you want I can run test of my own, if you can provide me with your current code -- it'll allow me to give you a better answer :-).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take notice of [this commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/10ed28b9d02ddc0b216889c7d37d452ac4b11324) Scrapy's author did yesterday:

> SitemapSpider: added support for sitemap urls ending in .xml and .xml.gz, even if they have a wrong content type

You could try cloning the latest version and re-try your spider.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem adding this to the "settings.py" file:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': None
}
```

Apparently this is a Scrapy bug: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/951